# How to end an NLTK chat bot?

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot

I am coding a chat bot and I want to break after typing *"thanks"* but I don't know how.
This is the code:

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections

words =[
        ['(hi|hey|hola|goodmorning|hay)', ['hello,how can i help you?']],
        ['(order|can i order)',['what size']],
        ['(my size is (.*))',['%1 is avalable'+' what color?']],
        ['(my color is (.*))',['%1 is avalable']],
        ['(how much)',['price is 300le' +  ' send your information ']],
        ['(my information is)',['order placed and will be delivered in 3 working days']],
        ['(thanks)',['you\'re welcome']],
       ]
        
chat = Chat(words, reflections) 
chat.converse()
```

I tried to use a `while` loop and it didn't work and also tried to use `break` at the end of the code also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The [`converse`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chat.util.html#nltk.chat.util.Chat.converse) method has a `quit` argument which signifies the input to end the conversation. Note that the bot will still respond to that input, and then end the conversation.

So in your case, you just need to add:

```
chat.converse(quit="thanks")
```